# JavaScript: Long list of properties alternatives

Tags: javascript

I have an object that already contains a pretty long list of properties and it's only going to grow. I'm looking for an alternative to just simply adding a new property every time one is needed but I'm not sure there is an alternative that is not only developer friendly, but non-tech savvy users can easily make changes/additions.

I've created a small version of my script that should explain what's going on.

```
const titles = {
  fr: 'Some text in french',
  fi: 'Some text in finnish'
  // tons more properties
}

const locale = window.location.url.split('/')[3]  // determines locale to use
const titleElement = document.querySelector('.title')
titleElement.innerText = titles[locale] | 'Some text in english'  // sets the titles text
```

## Edit

Some context would be helpful.

- I only have access through Adobe Target, specifically Recommendations
- All locales will be similar to the properties in the `titles` object in the code snippet

Comment: Are all your property-names language-codes (ne, de, se, en, it, es, pt, pl, ....)?

Comment: There's a slight lack of context here. Why are non-programmers amending your JavaScript code? Anyway, without knowing much about your setup, maybe you could store this data in a database instead of hard coded into the application? And then you could provide a little UI for other people to maintain the data as they see fit, without having to actually change code files. You might even be able to find a template for this kind of internationalised data store and application code to support it. It's a pretty common requirement

Comment: Does it have to be client side? You could always save the records into a database and just pull the language data depending on the user's selected language. That way its easier for non-tech savvy people to maintain and can grow. You just have to build the interface for them to add the language text.

Comment: You've outgrown manual file edits. Like all apps...scaling up involves adapting processes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"non-tech savvy users" should not be required to edit code. Instead, you should provide a way for them to enter data into your webapp and then store it more permanently on a server. Then the webapp reads that data when it is requested and does something with it.

Comment: I completely agree with you but the client is using Adobe Target for their project and I'm not seeing anything that allows them to access internal variables from a simple UI on the Target dashboard. I'll need to do some more digging to make sure.

Comment: @BrandonBenefield at some point, it becomes time to discuss issues that their process is going to cause and its limitations. If they have an existing website you can always persuade them that its time to implement a language editor in their CMS and just connect via ajax in Adobe Target.

Comment: "allows them to access internal variables from a simple UI" This sounds like the wrong approach to software engineering to me. Requirements gathering should be about what the user wants, in the domain language of the user, not the language of computer programming. This means that things like "access to internal variables" should not be part of the conversation. Instead, the conversation should be like "when I click on ... it should do ...".